# sailsjs on Heroku not creating model in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, heroku, sails.js, waterline

I am trying to use sails.js on Heroku. When I push my changes, the application starts, but when I try to run MyModel.find() methods, I receive an E_NOTFOUND error. When I log into the database with psql, I see that the tables have not been created automatically. I have the policy in `models.js` set to `migrate: 'drop'`, so shouldn't I at least get empty tables made when I launch the application? Is there something going on on Heroku that it doesn't like me running sails?

edit:
I had previously been putting settings in development.js and production.js that were different settings (heroku postgresql settings in production). I took that out, and put the settings in connections.js, and it seems like I am able to do the queries and such on the Models, however, when I do `heroku pg:psql` to connect to my database, I don't see the tables if I do "select * mytable;" it tells me no relation is found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem was that even though I had separate settings for development or production databases, when NODE_ENV was set to production, sails defaults to "safe" and will not let you change it to alter or drop - silently. Changing NODE_ENV to something else allowed the tables to be created.